# .htaccess URL redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This may be a simple question. But I am not good at .htaccess redirection rules, so I opened a question.

I want redirection like this:

If url like:  `www.mydomain.com/image/12345`, `www.mydomain.com/image/12346`.

do a redirection like:   `www.mydomain.com/products/image/12345`, `www.mydomain.com/products/image/12346`. (add `/products/` for the page if url end like `image/number` and no `/products/` for itself.)

I have already do some redirection rule like:

`RewriteRule ^(products/image)/(\d+)/?$ products/image?photo=$2`

in `.htaccss`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/?$ /products/image/$1 [L,R=301]
```

to redirect `www.mydomain.com/image/12345` to `www.mydomain.com/products/image/12345`. Then you're other rule should take affect and internally rewrite it.